# Proper way to deal with errors from subscribe call to Angular service

Tags: angular, error-handling, subscribe

I am an Angular newbie, so please excuse any flagrant errors if you see them. Feel free to point me in the right direction :)

I have an Angular service that calls a controller method. It used to be called like so, and it returned an object containing data used to display an image in the browser

```
      return (this.http.post(`/api/vehicles/${vehicleId}/photos`, formData)
         .map(res => res);
```

I was asked to implement a progress bar when uploading the image, so I added the reportProgress option to the http call. My service now has a property called uploadProgress that I can bind to my progress bar and display the progress of the upload.

```
@Injectable()
export class PhotoService {

   uploadProgress: any;

...
   upload(vehicleId, photo) {

      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', photo);

      const uploadReq = new HttpRequest('POST', `/api/vehicles/${vehicleId}/photos`, formData, {
         reportProgress: true
      });

      return (this.http.request(uploadReq)
         .map((event) => {
            if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
               this.uploadProgress = this.createProgress(event);
            } else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
               return event.body;
            }
         }));

   }

   private createProgress(event) {
      return {
         total: event.total,
         percentage: Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100)
      };
   }
```

The method on my form now looks like this

```
   uploadPhoto() {
      var nElem: HTMLInputElement = this.fileInput.nativeElement;

      var file = nElem.files[0];
      nElem.value = '';

      this.photoSvc.upload(this.vehicleId, file)
         .subscribe(photo => {
            this.progress = this.photoSvc.uploadProgress;
            console.log('this.progress: ', this.progress);
            if (photo !== undefined) {
               console.log('Photo result:', photo);
               this.photos.push(photo);
            }
         },
            err => {
               this.toasty.error({
                  title: 'Error',
                  msg: err.text(),
                  theme: 'bootstrap',
                  showClose: true,
                  timeout: 5000
               });
         },
         () => { this.progress = null; });
   }
```

The subscribe blockis fired a number of times and I use it to update the "this.progress" variable that is bound to the progress bar. It works, I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this but it works. If its not the right way feel free to elaborate.

The issue I now have that I cannot figure out is that if my edge cases in the controller (file size, file type, empty file etc) are exercised, they return BadRequest errors like the samples below, but my err block on  the subscribe does not catch them, so the toast message does not display. Instead it goes to my global error handler. I wanted to display more meaningful messages in this upload instead of the generic toast message the system now puts out.

```
if (file == null) { return BadRequest("Null file"); }
if (file.Length == 0) { return BadRequest("Empty file"); }
```

Any help on what is going on here is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so blame this one on copy and paste. I realized my err block was not correct when my sentry.io code posted an error "err.text is not a function". I used

```
            err => {
               this.toasty.error({
                  title: 'Error',
                  msg: err.text(),
                  theme: 'bootstrap',
                  showClose: true,
                  timeout: 5000
               });
         }
```

instead of

```
            err => {
               this.toasty.error({
                  title: 'Error',
                  msg: err.error,
                  theme: 'bootstrap',
                  showClose: true,
                  timeout: 5000
               });
         }
```

and once fixed, the code worked fine. Sorry for the trouble, its getting late...